cannot retrieve value from useState variable react-native
So Im having trouble using a variable that is assigned with the useState hook from react-native. Here is my code.
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FlatButton from "../ui/FlatButton";
import { COLORS } from "../../constants/styles";
import { getPreSignedUrl } from "../../utils/storage";
import IconButton from "../ui/IconButton";
import { leaveCommunity } from "../../utils/community";
import { getCommunityUserByCommunityId } from "../../utils/community";
import { currentSession } from "../../utils/auth";

function CommunityDetails({ community }) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [statistics, setStatistics] = useState(false);
    const [coverPicture, setCoverPicture] = useState('');
    const [communityUser, setCommunityUser] = useState('');
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        getMyId();
        getCoverPicture();
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: '',
            headerBackTitle: 'Back',
            headerRight: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <IconButton
                    icon="close"
                    size={24}
                    color={tintColor}
                    onPress={handleLeaveCommuntiyAlert}
                />
            ),
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        handleCommunityUser();
    }, [userId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Community user:', communityUser);
    }, [communityUser]);

    async function getMyId() {
        try {
            const userInfo = await currentSession();
            const userName = userInfo.idToken.payload['cognito:username'];
            console.log('My user id: ' + userName);
            setUserId(userName);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error fetching user information: ' + error);
        }
    }

    async function handleCommunityUser() {
        try {
            const communityUserResponse = await getCommunityUserByCommunityId(community.id);
            const communityUsers = communityUserResponse.data.communityUsersByCommunityId.items;
            console.log('Community users:', communityUsers);
            const user = communityUsers.find(user => user.userId == userId);
            console.log('User found:', user);
            if (user) {
                console.log('User ID:', user.id);
                setCommunityUser(user.id);
            } else {
                console.log('No user found for the current user ID');
                setCommunityUser(null);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error fetching community users:', error);
        }
    }

    async function handleLeaveCommuntiyAlert() {
        Alert.alert('Are you sure you want to leave this community? btw this is your communityId: '+communityUser, '', [
            { text: 'Yes', onPress: handleLeaveCommuntiy },
            { text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel') }
        ]);
    }

    async function handleLeaveCommuntiy() {
        console.log('Leaving community with this id:', communityUser);
        if (!communityUser) {
            console.log('Community user is not set. Cannot leave community.');
            return;
        }
        const leavedCommunity = await leaveCommunity(communityUser);
        navigation.navigate('Community', { all: true });
        console.log(leavedCommunity);
    }

    async function getCoverPicture() {
        console.log('Getting cover picture');
        const file = await getPreSignedUrl(community.coverPicture, 'guest', userId);
        setCoverPicture(file.url);
    }

    function handlePosts() {
        setStatistics(false);
    }

    function handleStatistics() {
        setStatistics(true);
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{community.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.communityHeader}>
                    <Text>Here comes the header</Text>
                    <Button onPress={getCoverPicture} title="Get cover picture" />
                </View>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
                        <View>
                            <FlatButton onPress={handlePosts}>Posts</FlatButton>
                            <View style={!statistics ? styles.selectedTab : styles.notSelectedTab}></View>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <FlatButton onPress={handleStatistics}>Statistics</FlatButton>
                            <View style={statistics ? styles.selectedTab : styles.notSelectedTab}></View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Here comes the content</Text>
                        <Text>This is my community user ID: {communityUser}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    filterContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    selectedTab: {
        width: '30%',
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: '35%',
    },
    notSelectedTab: {
        width: '30%',
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: '35%',
    },
    communityHeader: {
        height: 200,
    },
    image: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    },
});

export default CommunityDetails;

So the problem is with the communityUser as you see in the code I can print it in my component but when I try to leave in the alert box you can see that it should also print it but this never happens. I find this weird as I can print the Id inside the component. Anyone have an idea why this is happening. Thanks in advance

You are badly misusing useEffect dependencies. Your first effect depends on getMyId (which also depends on currentSession) and getCoverPicture (which also depends on community.coverPicture and userId). Your second effect lists userId it's not referenced in the effect body, however you do use handleCommunityUser which also depends on community.id, userId. You need to revisit the useEffect docs or see The Complete Guide to useEffect.

For starters, try updating the first effect dependencies array to [getMyId, getCoverPicture] and the second effect dependencies to [handleCommunityUser]. Your third effect is the only one that is written correctly.

After you master useEffect, next you should read You Might Not Need an Effect.
